# Contents repeat when I try to change them using f.open python in linux

Tags: python, linux

My code is of this format

```
#!/usr/bin/python

fout = open("names2", "w")
fin = open("names", "r")

for line in fin:
   fout.write(line.replace('Smith','Mr.Smith'))
   fout.write(line.replace('Walker','Mr.Walker'))

fout.close()
```

My sample file is

```
Smith           Anderson        Clark           Wright          Mitchell
Johnson         Thomas          Rodriguez       Lopez           Perez
Williams        Jackson         Lewis           Hill            Roberts
Jones           White           Lee             Scott           Turner
Brown           Harris          Walker          Green           Phillips
Davis           Martin          Hall            Adams           Campbell
Miller          Thompson        Allen           Baker           Parker
Wilson          Garcia          Young           Gonzalez        Evans
Moore           Martinez        Hernandez       Nelson          Edwards
Taylor          Robinson        King            Carter          Collins
```

Instead of getting Smith changed to Mr.Smith and Walker by Mr.Walker, I get

```
Mr.Smith                Anderson        Clark           Wright          Mitchell
Smith           Anderson        Clark           Wright          Mitchell
Johnson         Thomas          Rodriguez       Lopez           Perez
Johnson         Thomas          Rodriguez       Lopez           Perez
Williams        Jackson         Lewis           Hill            Roberts
Williams        Jackson         Lewis           Hill            Roberts
Jones           White           Lee             Scott           Turner
Jones           White           Lee             Scott           Turner
Brown           Harris          Walker          Green           Phillips
Brown           Harris          Mr.Walker               Green           Phillips
Davis           Martin          Hall            Adams           Campbell
Davis           Martin          Hall            Adams           Campbell
Miller          Thompson        Allen           Baker           Parker
Miller          Thompson        Allen           Baker           Parker
Wilson          Garcia          Young           Gonzalez        Evans
Wilson          Garcia          Young           Gonzalez        Evans
Moore           Martinez        Hernandez       Nelson          Edwards
Moore           Martinez        Hernandez       Nelson          Edwards
Taylor          Robinson        King            Carter          Collins
Taylor          Robinson        King            Carter          Collins
```

Which means for every for, the files creates an extra instance and the lines are duplicated which I don''t want happening. I there are work around? I have Python 2.4.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's becase you are writing the line twice.

Change your loop to:

```
for line in fin:
    line = line.replace('Smith','Mr.Smith')
    line = line.replace('Walker','Mr.Walker')
    fout.write(line)
```

Comment: What if I wanted to change the whole line? like make
    Brown           Harris          Walker          Green           Phillips
to
    Mr.Brown        Mr.Harris      Mr.Walker        Green           Phillips?

Comment: Then you are probably better with an regular expression substitution. Try adding `import re` to the top, and using: `line = re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'Mr. \1', line)` for the substitutions inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is to apply chained `str.replace` calls:

```
for line in fin:
   fout.write(line.replace('Smith', 'Mr.Smith').replace('Walker','Mr.Walker'))
```

But note that one problem with `str.replace` is that this will also affect string like `Smithy`, to handle that case use regex with word boundaries or convert each line from file to a list first and then change the items in that list.

Comment: What if I wanted to change the whole line? like make
    Brown           Harris          Walker          Green           Phillips
to
    Mr.Brown        Mr.Harris      Mr.Walker        Green           Phillips?

Comment: elias idea seems more helpful for my application. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No `Mr.` in front of `Green` and  `Phillips`?

Comment: No. Some of the contents are required to be the same. this is like an example of what my code should be. my actual file has stuff that muct never be changed!